# X11 Create a window without showing up on taskbar

Tags: c, linux, x11

Is it possible to create a window without it showing up on taskbar in X11 using c?

Comment: that depends on the window manager, and you need to modify some atoms. can't say more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on GUI toolkit you are using. For example, GTK+ provides [`gdk_window_set_skip_taskbar_hint`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-skip-taskbar-hint) function.

If you don't use any GUI toolkit and directly interface X11, you need to add `_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR` atom to [`_NET_WM_STATE`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#idm140238712324208) property.